# Putting the link in navigation bar

Tags: magento2, footer-links

How can i change or move the link that when i click the (Contact us) in navigation bar the output will be the same in (contact us) in footer?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a link to  navigation then you need to create a plugin

on `Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu` and use  `before` plugin on `_getHtml()`

create di.xml where  we will define plugin

**app\code{VendorName}{ModuleName}\etc\di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu">
        <plugin name="add_contact_us_menu" type="{VendorName}{ModuleName}\Plugin\Topmenu" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config
```

**Now create the plugin class where we will add a contact us page link to menu.**

```
<?php 
namespace {VendorName}\{ModuleName}\Plugin;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\NodeFactory;
class Topmenu
{
    protected $nodeFactory;
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $_urlBuilder;

    public function __construct(
        NodeFactory $nodeFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder
    ) {
        $this->nodeFactory = $nodeFactory;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
    }
    public function beforeGetHtml(
        \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu $subject,
        $outermostClass = '',
        $childrenWrapClass = '',
        $limit = 0
    ) {



        $node = $this->nodeFactory->create(
            [
                'data' => [
                    'name' => 'Contact US',
                    'id' => 'contact-us-page',
                    'url' =>  $this->_urlBuilder->getUrl('contact'),
                    'has_active' => false,
                    'is_active' => false // (expression to determine if menu item is selected or not)
                ],
                'idField' => 'id',
                'tree' => $subject->getMenu()->getTree()
            ]
        );
        $subject->getMenu()->addChild($node);
    }


}
```

More detail get  at  [here](http://www.amitbera.com/magento2-add-a-cms-page-link-to-menu/)

Comment: I don't want to create a cms i just want to redirect the link of (Contact Us) footer in the (Contact Us) navigation bar.

Comment: Don't create any cms page. What you want navigation Contact Us redirect to  (Contact Us) footer link? Have u already  create ` Contact Us` , is this link a category?

Comment: The default footer have a contact us cms page. I want that to show when i click the Contact Us navigation bar.

Comment: if your contact us  is a cms page then http://www.amitbera.com/magento2-add-a-cms-page-link-to-menu/ blog will help you

Comment: Sorry i don't have a module